# Asynchronously process entities as they are returned from the database engine

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await, entity-framework-6

In EF 6, I would like to asynchronously process entities as they are returned from the database engine.

I know I can call `ToListAsync()` and `ForEachAsync()` and perhaps they do what I'm looking for, but I'm not convinced.  I think what I am looking for is the combination of the two.

From my understanding, `ToListAsync()` will complete the task when the entire query is read from the database engine and converted to entities.  Which means you have to wait for the entire query to return before beginning to process.

I can't determine if `ForEachAsync()` does what I'm looking for but what I am assuming, due to not finding information elsewhere, is that `ForEachAsync()` simply works on an already-retrieved collection and the processing of each item is async.

What would be ideal is that `ForEachAsync()` (or another yet unknown method) would call the task as the data was being retrieved from the database engine.

So... does `ForEachAsync()` actually do this, and if not, is there a way for it to be done?

The reasons for wanting this are twofold:

1. Large queries don't need to be stored in memory as the entire
   collection, so savings in memory footprint and ability to process 
   much larger resultsets not constrained by memory
2. The duration of the whole
   process will likely be shorter due to processing each item during
   latency of data retrieval

**Update:** Basically, if a `DbContext` raised an event like `OnEntityLoaded` for each entity when you called `LoadAsync()`, I could accomplish everything that I want.  Because I could then just enqueue the entity to a separate task processor and the entities could be processed efficiently and take advantage of any I/O latency.  I can always tune the separate task processor, so I don't really need EF to support asynchronous processing of the entities, just asynchronously load and fire an event/call a delegate on each entity load.

**Update 2:** And if `ForEachAsync()` was called as the entities were being loaded, then that would also accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: So you're looking for something that will automatically retrieve the items from the database in chunks or one at a time? Typically, an EF query will pull multiple items from the database in a single DB query.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for.  The net result is that I'd like an asynchronous data reader (like SqlDataReader) that asynchronously emits/processes entities.  I could write something with async SqlDataReader but I'd like it to use EF6 entities and work within EF6.

Comment: @JLRishe, I added an edit to the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForEachAsync`, unlike `ToListAsync`, doesn't get all the items in advance and just lets you iterate over it. The iteration is `async` itself.

`QueryableExtensions.ForEachAsync` delegates over to `IDbAsyncEnumerable.ForEachAsync` [which is this](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.cs):

```
internal static async Task ForEachAsync(
    this IDbAsyncEnumerable source, Action<object> action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    DebugCheck.NotNull(source);
    DebugCheck.NotNull(action);

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    using (var enumerator = source.GetAsyncEnumerator())
    {
        if (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken).WithCurrentCulture())
        {
            Task<bool> moveNextTask;
            do
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                var current = enumerator.Current;
                moveNextTask = enumerator.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken);
                action(current);
            }
            while (await moveNextTask.WithCurrentCulture());
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that it's very similar to how an iteration over `IEnumerable` is made but with `async-await` in mind. Instead of `IEnumerable`, `GetEnumerator`, `IEnumerator` and `MoveNext` we have [`IDbAsyncEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbasyncenumerable(v=vs.113).aspx), [`GetAsyncEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbasyncenumerable.getasyncenumerator(v=vs.113).aspx), [`IDbAsyncEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbasyncenumerator(v=vs.113).aspx) and [`MoveNextAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.idbasyncenumerator.movenextasync(v=vs.113).aspx).

`MoveNextAsync` allows to actually asynchronously retrieve items when needed.

Comment: So then `ForEachAsync` depends on the implementation of `IDbAsyncEnumerable` to be properly implemented instead of just providing a pseudo-async interface.  I'll either need to do some profiling while debugging a large dataset or dig into the code of the SQL Server EF provider.  Guessing the profiling will get me a quicker answer :)

Comment: @MikeJansen `QueryableExtensions.ForEachAsync` works on `IQueryable` but can't assume `IQueryable` has `MoveNextAsync` so it checks whether the parameter in this case is an `IDbAsyncEnumerable` and otherwise throws an exception. If you use `ForEachAsync` and don't get an exception you're using `IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ForEachAsync`

Comment: RIght, what I was getting at is that the `IDbAsyncEnumerable` implementation needs to enumerate as the data is coming in, and not just enumerate "asynchronously" after the data is all local.  I don't see anything in the contract or description that says how `IDbAsyncEnumerable` needs to enumerate in relationship to data retrieval, and it's not uncommon for asynchronous patterns to be implemented less-than-optimally.  Your answer was very useful and I've marked it as the correct answer, since what I'm pondering goes beyond my original question.

Comment: @MikeJansen You can see that the enumeration itself is `async`. Are you suggesting `MoveNextAsync` is implemented synchronously?

Comment: @MikeJansen because it eventually reaches [Shaper.StoreReadAsync](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Common/internal/materialization/Shaper`.cs) which uses .Net's [DbDataReader.ReadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223697(v=vs.110).aspx)